# ML preprocess to achieve stationarity

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, stationarity

I would like to use Machine learning models on top of  multivariate time series data to forecast long horizons (for example 400 items and their historical sales in the last year & content features).

From many papers, blogs and Kaggle notebooks I understood that the time series must be stationary,  before  I am using classical ML algorithms. The reason that ML models such XG-boost\ Cat-Boost can't extrapolate to the feature .

If I enforce the variance and mean being stationary & adding seasonal attributes ( such as LAGS ) , then it should be fine :)

To make variance stationary  I can use log , or Box-Cox power transformation.

Though for mean , I can’t find a practical approach to enforce stationarity  . I tried to use differencing – but since I have a long horizon  ( such as future 90 points ) I got very bad results.

And I do familiar with two types of trend : stochastic and deterministic

some one can assist with how to enforce stationary to the mean , and then transform back  the predictions to their original scale ?
And if anyone has some Python code example to such task it will be great ! :)

Comment: Hi: AFAIK, differencing is the only way to possibly obtain stationarity in the mean. But even that might not work if the trend is not  smooth.

Comment: It's not the only was. Harmonic terms can be filtered out through Spectral analysis.

Comment: @mlofton, differencing works for stochastic trends. There can be deterministic trends, too, in which case one can model that and subtract the fitted trend from the series to achieve stationarity.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Good point about fitting trend. Michael ChermicK: Good point also but I don't think that's used to achieve stationarity but rather for de-seasonalizing ? I guess if the seasonality is the only non-stationarity, then you are correct. thanks for both comments.